# Infinite Loop Issue - Intersections

Tags: python, tkinter, line, infinite-loop, overlap

I tried out a system that hopefully will prevent the line from crossing over itself. However, when ran it created what appears to be an infinite loop. I am not sure what the issue is. Here is the code.

```
#detecting the overlap
intersection1 = Line1.intersection(Line1)

while Line1 == intersection1:
    importlib.reload(tkinter)
    print('failed attempt')
    continue

    while Line1 != intersection1:
        print('successful attempt')
        break
```

In order to run the program, the full code is needed which I will list below, but above is the section in question.

```
#imports
import tkinter
from tkinter import * 
import random
from random import randint
import math
import time

import pip 
import shapely
from shapely.geometry import LineString
import importlib

#setting up the canvas
master = Tk()
master.geometry("500x500")
master.title("Sprouts")

w = Canvas(master, width=500, height=500, bg="white")
w.pack()

#creating the circle
def create_circle(x, y, r, w): #center coordinates, radius
    x0 = x - r
    y0 = y - r
    x1 = x + r
    y1 = y + r
    return w.create_oval(x0, y0, x1, y1)

#creating coordinate variables
xC = random.randint(10,490)
yC = random.randint(10,490)
xC2 = random.randint(10,490)
yC2 = random.randint(10,490)

L1C1 = random.randint(10,490)
L1C2 = random.randint(10,490)
L1C3 = random.randint(10,490)
L1C4 = random.randint(10,490)

#displaying the circle
c1 = create_circle(xC, yC, 5, w)
c2 = create_circle(xC2, yC2, 5, w)

#displaying the line #implementing the curve
Line1 = LineString([(xC, yC), (xC2, yC2)]
              or [(xC, yC), (L1C1, L1C2), (xC2, yC2)]
              or [(xC,yC), (L1C1, L1C2), (L1C3, L1C4), (xC2, yC2)])

Line1show = w.create_line(xC, yC, xC2, yC2 or
                          xC, yC, L1C1, L1C2, xC2, yC2 or
                          xC, yC, L1C1, L1C2, L1C3, L1C4, xC2, yC2,
                          smooth='1',width="2")

#detecting the overlap
intersection1 = Line1.intersection(Line1)

while Line1 == intersection1:
    importlib.reload(tkinter)
    print('failed attempt')
    continue

    while Line1 != intersection1:
        print('sucessful attempt')
        break 
                 
w.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the use of `continue` which return you all the way back to the beginning of your loop

here is a simple illustrative example that do the same as your problematic code section

```
>>> msj=""
>>> while msj!="yes":
        print("msj is not 'yes'")
        continue
        msj=input("write msj")


msj is not 'yes'
msj is not 'yes'
msj is not 'yes'
...
```

here you would never get to the `msj=input("write msj")` because the `continue` return to the beginning of the loop and the previous part make no change to the condition of the loop hence you end in an infinite loop...

A more correct use of `continue` is with conditionals `if` statements in order to skip doing stuff with something you don't need to work on like for example in pseudocode something like this:

```
while dowork:
    if not condition(data):
        continue
    result=work_on_data(data)
    if check_if_done(result):
        break
    data=get_next_data()
```